# Python client server how UDP is supposed to work?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a client-server "snake" game working really well with TCP connections, and I would like to try it the UDP way.

I wonder how it is supposed to be used ? I know how UDP works, how to make a simple ECHO example, but I wonder how to do the following :

For instance with TCP, every TICK (1/15 second) server sends to the client the new Snake head position.

With UDP, am I supposed to do something like this :

Client SIDE :

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverAddr = (('localhost', PORT))
while 1:
    client.sendto('askForNewHead', serverAddr)
    msg, addrServer = client.recvfrom(1024)
    game.addPosition(msg)
```

Server SIDE :

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
    data, addr = server.recvfrom(1024)
    server.sendto(headPosition, addr)
```

So here Client has to ask server to get the new head position, and then server sends the answer. I managed to make it work this way, but I can't figure out if it is a good way of doing.

Seems weird that client has to ask udp for an update while with my TCP connection, client has just to wait untill he receives a message.

Comment: Unless you've got something like a firewall with stateful packet-forwarding rules between the client and the server, the client does not need to send UDP packets to the server in order to get UDP packets from the server.  i.e. barring any meddling, the traffic flows are independent of each other.  Note that (just like with TCP) recvfrom() will block by default until a packet is received; that might be related to your problem.  You can avoid that by either setting the socket to non-blocking mode or using select() to implement a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences between TCP and UDP but not the way you describe. Like with TCP the client can recvfrom to get messages from the server without asking each time for new data. The differences are:

- With TCP the initial connect includes a packet exchange between client and server. Unless the client socket was already bound to an IP and port it will be bound to the clients IP and a free port will be allocated. Because of the handshake between client and server the server knows where to contact the client and thus can send data to the packet without getting data from the client before.
- With UDP there is no initial handshake. Unless already bound, the socket will be bound to clients IP and a free port when sending the first packet to the server. Only when receiving this packet the server knows the IP and port of the client and can send data back.

Which means, that you don't need to 'askForNewHead' all the time. Instead the client has to send only a single packet to the server so that the server knows where to send all future packets.

But there are other important differences between TCP and UDP:

- With UDP packets may be lost or could arrive in a different order. With TCP you have a guaranteed delivery.
- With UDP there is no real connection, only an exchange of packets between two peers. With TCP you have the start and end of a connection. This is relevant for packet filters in firewalls or router, which often need to maintain the state of a connection. Because UDP has no end-of-connection the packet filters will just use a simple timeout, often as low as 30 seconds. Thus, if the client is inside a home network and waits passively for data from server, it might wait forever if the packet filter closed the state because of the timeout. To work around this data have to be transmitted in regular intervals so that the state does not time out.

One often finds the argument, that UDP is faster then TCP. This is plain wrong. But you might see latency problems if packets get lost because TCP will notice packet loss and send the packet again and also reduce wire speed to loose less packets. With UDP instead you have to deal with the packet loss and other congestion problems yourself. There are situations like real time audio, where it is ok to loose some packets but low latency is important. These are situations where UDP is good, but in most other situations TCP is better.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is different to TCP, and I believe with python the client does have to ask for an update from the server.
Although it is fun to learn and use a different way of communicating over the internet, for python I would really recommend sticking with TCP.

Comment: The motivation is that I would like to try something faster as it is for a speed/real-time based game. And TCP congestion is making few 'lags' that can happen up to 10 times in an hour.

Comment: Have you tried [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/)?  

EDIT: UDT is meant to be a link, although on my display I can't quite make it out.

Comment: These 'lags' with TCP are where you would loose the packets instead with UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to ask the server for a update. But since UDP is connection-less the server can send head-positions without being asked. But the client should send i'm-alive-packets to the server, but this could happen every 10 seconds or so.